# Gamecenter "Welcome"-Banner not showing up

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, game-center

I have a problem with Gamecenter. Actually I don't know if its really a problem.

**After authenticating my localPlayer the "Welcome"-Banner does not show up.
Why is that? Is that a sign that something is wrong?**

I wrote my first app with Swift and SpriteKit with Gamecenter integration. When I open my app, Gamecenter authenticates my localPlayer just fine.

```
GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated     // is true
```

Opening up the Leaderboard works fine too. If I log out of Gamecenter and open my App again it asks me to log in with the view Gamecenter provides.

Showing a GKNotification is also no problem. Pops up right away.

This is my code to authenticate the player:

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer(){
    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in
        if ((viewController) != nil) {
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            println("(GameCenter) Player authenticated: \(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated)")   
        }

    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your authenticateLocalPlayer()

Comment: In my GameViewController and is called in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Call it in app delegate

Comment: That is in deed a better way. The player is now authenticated in AppDelegate and if not authenticated the viewController is presented correctly. Unfortunately there is still no "Welcome back"-Banner

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to authenticate with Game Center, and I had never a problem with it (always a welcome banner):

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer() {
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler =
        { (viewController : UIViewController?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
            if viewController != nil
            {
                self.presentViewController(viewController!, animated:true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                if localPlayer.authenticated
                {
                    print("Player authenticated")
                    self.gameCenterEnabled = true
                    isAuthenticated = true
                    localPlayer.loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler
                        { (leaderboardIdentifier, error) -> Void in
                            if error != nil
                            {
                                print("error", appendNewline: false)
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                self.leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier
                                print("\(self.leaderboardIdentifier)")
                            }
                    }
                }   else {
                    print("Not able to authenticate")
                    self.gameCenterEnabled = false

                    if error != nil
                    {
                        print("\(error!.description)")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("error is nil")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```